# How can i populate all images of an arraylist into an imageview of a recyclerview?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, imageview

Im populating an arraylist of images from firebase and their links from firestore into an imageview of a recyclerview. The arrayList logs all data but shows only the first index of an aray on an imageview.

```
class AgriBusinessAdapter(private val context : Context, private val agriArrayList: ArrayList<AgriBusinessModel>, private val onCallBack: AgriBusinessAdapter.OnCallBack) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AgriBusinessAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // passing our layout file for displaying our card item
       return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_agri, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // setting data to our text views from our modal class.
        val agriModel: AgriBusinessModel = agriArrayList[position]

        holder.nameV.text = agriModel.name

        agriModel.images?.forEachIndexed { index, uri ->
            Picasso.get().load(uri).into(holder.images)
            Log.d("index", index.toString())
            Log.d("uri", uri)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        // returning the size of our array list.
        return agriArrayList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        // creating variables for our views.

            val nameV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name)
            var images : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageFromDb)

    }
    interface OnCallBack {
        fun onCallBack(view: View, category: AgriBusinessModel)
        fun onSelect(category: AgriBusinessModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you have an array (**more than one**) of image uris, but you have **only one** ImageView? How do you plan to fit all these images in one view?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Rosário asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: I have solved it, I created an inner adapter class for the images as the images have an array property. I was lost at first because I tried to loop textViews using forEachIndexed and it was working but when I changed to imageView it had a different behaviour.